# Managing Twitter Bootstrap repository using deps in Symfony2 and assetic

Tags: git, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, assetic

I'd like to manage [Twitter Bootstrap git repository](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/) using deps file in Symfony2. So i added these lines:

```
[TwitterBootstrap]
    git=https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
    target=/twitter
    version=v2.0.3
```

and the repository is cloned into `Symfony2\vendor\twitter\bootstrap`.

Im' stuck ad this: **how can i import** the relevant css/js using assetic and **how cssrewrite rule works** when images are placed into `Symfony2\vendor\twitter\bootstrap\img` instead of `Symfony2\app\Resources\public\img`.

```
 {% stylesheets '????????????????' filter='cssrewrite' %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
 {% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I compile Bootstrap's LESS to CSS:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        '../vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
        output='css/bootstrap.css'
    %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've installed [`lessphp`](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp) — you could use Node.js instead — as a vendor and activated it like this:

```
assetic:
    debug: %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        lessphp:
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
```

As for the `cssrewrite` filter, you don't need it in this case. If you somehow get Bootstrap images to the `web/img` folder, it will work. I'm still looking for a neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using MopaBootstrapBundle which implements twitter bundle to symfony2? https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle

I'm also working on implementing HTML5Boilerplate + TwitterBundle generated via http://Initializr.com on https://github.com/nysander/MopaBootstrapBundle/tree/initializr branch

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by making a symbolic link to vendor/twitter-bootstrap in my web directory (if you don't, the images will never be reachable). But I don't remember using twitter-bootstrap images.

I don't import bootstrap in my twig templates, but in the less file of my project, like this:

```
@import "../../../twitter-bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
```

But I've had many headaches with this method. See this bug report I wrote: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/202

Answer (score 0):

MopaBootstrapBundle seems more flexible as stated by @nysander.

<strike>If you want a raw implementation of twitter-bootstrap, without any helper, this repository aims to provide Twitter Bootstrap as an asset for Symfony by encapsulating it in a public folder : https://github.com/chasen/bootstrap</strike>

Comment: you should add README.md and state which version of Twitter Bootstrap this bundle privides, existing tags and branches are misleading ;/

Comment: That's ok, I just thought that you are developer of it. Greets